# Quantitative global Schauder estimate for solution operator to second order elliptic equation via extension

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, elliptic-pde, linear-pde

Let $\Omega\to\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded Lipschitz domain. We can choose an extension operator $E$ such that $E:W^{k,p}(\Omega)\to W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ is bounded for all $k\ge0$ and $1<p<\infty$, for example, the Stein's extension. Let $N(x)$ be the Newtonian potential, so $\mathcal Nf:=(N\ast Ef)|_\Omega$ is a solution operator to the Laplacian equation $\Delta u=f$ and has boundedness $\mathcal N:W^{k,p}(\Omega)\to W^{k+2,p}(\Omega)$ for all $k\ge0$ and $1<p<\infty$.

Let $A=(a^{ij})_{n\times n}:\Omega\to\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ be a smooth matrix function. For the second order elliptic problem $\Delta u=f+\partial_i(a^{ij}\partial_j)u$ we can take the solution operator $T_Af:=(I-\mathcal N\partial_i(a^{ij}\partial_j))^{-1}\circ\mathcal N f$.

My question is, when $\|A\|_{L^\infty}<\frac12$ (say taking matrix operator norm for $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$), do we have estimate $\|T_A-\mathcal N\|_{W^{k,p}(\Omega)\to W^{k+2,p}(\Omega)}\le C_{\Omega,k,p}\|A\|_{C^k}$, for all $k\ge0$ and $1<p<\infty$?

Note that when $A$ has small $C^k$ norm, the operator $\mathcal N\partial_i(a^{ij}\partial_j)$ is a contraction mapping and the result follow immediately. Using the paraproducts or the formula like $\|uv\|_{W^{k,p}}\le C_{k,p}(\|u\|_{C^0}\|v\|_{W^{k,p}}+\|u\|_{C^k}\|v\|_{L^p})$ one can have the result for $\|A\|_{C^0}<\delta_{k,p}$ for some small constant depending on $k,p$ (and also the extension $E$ and the domain $\Omega$). I don't know how to make the small norm assumption independent of $k$ and $p$.